# How to simulate the time response of a system transfer function with python-control (IVP problem)?

Tags: python, differential-equations, transfer-function, python-control

I'm trying to demonstrate how to "solve" (simulate the solution) of differential equation  initial value problems (IVP) using both the definition of the system transfer function and the `python-control` module. The fact is I'm really a newbie regarding control.

I have this simple differential as an example: `y'' - 4y' + 13y = 0`, with these initial conditions: `y(0) = 1` and `y'(0) = 0`.

I achieve this transfer function by hand:
`Y(s) = (s - 4)/(s^2 - 4*s + 13)`.

So, in Python, I'm writing this little piece of code (note that `y_ans` is the answer of this differential IVP as [seen here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27+-+4y%27+%2B+13y+%3D+0%2C+y(0)+%3D+1%2C+y%27(0)+%3D+0)):

```
import numpy as np
import control as ctl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0., 1.5, 100)
sys = ctl.tf([1.,-4.],[1.,-4.,13.])
T, yout, _ = ctl.forced_response(sys, T=t, X0=[1, 0])

y_ans = lambda x: 1/3*np.exp(2*x)*(3*np.cos(3*x) - 2*np.sin(3*x))

plt.plot(t, y_ans(t), '-.', color='gray', alpha=0.5, linewidth=3, label='correct answer')
plt.plot(T, yout, 'r', label='simulated')
plt.legend()
```

This code gets me this graph:

[image: original plots]

But when I insert a negative sign in front of `yout`, I got a match as I'd like it to be:

```
plt.plot(T, -yout, 'r', label='simulated') ### yout with negative sign
```

[image: fliped simulation plot]

What am I doing wrong? Python-control documentation is not very clear to me. Also, I don't know if my interpretation of `X0` parameter for `control.forced_response` is correct. Is it possible to do this as I'm intended of doing?

Anyone who can shed a light on this subject is welcome to contribute.

**EDIT**

Setting `X0 = [0,0]` gives me this graph:

[image]

Comment: It seems as  if you encode the initial conditions twice in `forced_response`, once in the numerator of the transfer function and then again in `X0`. Try setting `X0=[0,0]`. You might have implemented the solution for `(s-4)^2/(s^2-4s+13)`.

Comment: Thanks, @LutzLehmann, but when I set `X0=[0,0]` or if I let it to its default, the result is a zeroed flat line on the abscissa (I included the graph in the question, edit section).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @LutzLehmann, I've being thinking on the meaning of "encode twice" some stuff. So, back to square one, I realized that this transfer function incorporates both input (time or ramp) and initial conditions. It is actually an output. I need some sort of inverse laplace transform or, as I start to think, I'd need only to simulate it as it is, without further information.

Therefore, I managed to use an impulse input (which laplace transform is equal to 1) and I was able to get an output that was exactly my tf simulated in time.

```
import numpy as np
import control as ctl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0., 1.5, 100)
sys = ctl.tf([1.,-4.],[1.,-4.,13.])
T, yout = ctl.impulse_response(sys, T=t) # HERE is what I wanted

y_ans = lambda x: 1/3*np.exp(2*x)*(3*np.cos(3*x) - 2*np.sin(3*x))

plt.plot(t, y_ans(t), '-.', color='gray', alpha=0.5, linewidth=3, label='correct answer')
plt.plot(T, yout, 'r', label='simulated')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Now I think I can show how to use python-control to indirectly simulate answers for differential equations. :-D

Answer (score 1):

I think the best thing to do here is to convert your system to state space and have a look at what is going on (there are many possible state space representations):

```
sys_tf = ctl.tf([1.,-4.],[1.,-4.,13.])
sys_ss = ctl.tf2ss(sys_tf)
print(sys_ss)
```

Output:

```
A = [[ 4.00000000e+00  1.30000000e+00]
     [-1.00000000e+01  1.33226763e-15]]

B = [[-1.]
     [ 0.]]

C = [[-1.  -0.4]]

D = [[0.]]
```

We want to find `x(0)` such that `y(0) = Cx(0) = 1` and `y'(0) = CAx(0) = 0`.

We can either write out these equations and solve them by hand or use linear algebra:

```
A = np.vstack([sys_ss.C, sys_ss.C @ sys_ss.A])
b = np.array([[1], [0]])
x0 = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
print(x0)
```

gives:

```
[[-1.00000000e+00]
 [-1.36642834e-15]]
```

Therefore, this should work:

```
T, yout = ctl.forced_response(sys_ss, T=t, X0=[-1, 0])
```

Also, since you are only interested in the transient response to the initial condition (i.e. `u(t)=0`) you can use the [`initial_response`](https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.3/generated/control.initial_response.html#control-initial-response) function:

```
T, yout = ctl.initial_response(sys_ss, T=t, X0=[-1, 0])
```

Comment: If one checks the original code in the recent version 0.9.0 one sees that the behavior in the question no longer exists.

Comment: That's true although I was able to replicate the results in the question by making a slight change to the code: `T, yout = ctl.forced_response(sys, T=t, X0=[1, 0])`.  Therefore I think my answer is still relevant.